# Synergy - 2 computers, 3 monitors. middle monitor for its own pc

Tags: multiple-monitors, synergy

Currently my only PC is my server and a gaming PC. When the server is under a heavy load, gaming performance tanks, so I'm going to be building a gaming PC.   The gaming PC will have 1 monitor while the server will have the other two.  The gaming PC's monitor will be in the middle.

```
[Server monitor 1][Gaming PC monitor][Server Monitor 2]
```

I'd like to know if Synergy can support the following:

Moving left from the gaming pc's monitor(middle monitor) will go to the server's screen on the left.  Moving right from the gaming PC's monitor will go to the server's right screen.  If you go off the right side of the right most monitor, it should go to the left of the left most monitor.

Comment: Hey, I answered your question. Could you accept the answer if it looks good to you? Otherwise, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: Are you sure you can't do this natively in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - I got an email back from a Synergy competitor (Multiplicity) and they claim to be able to do this.  You'd have to set up things a little different but it's possible:

The setup would still be this:
[Server monitor 1][Gaming PC monitor][Server Monitor 2]

But in windows you do the following:
[server monitor 2][server monitor 1][gaming pc]

Then you enable mouse wrapping in their software.  They claim now when you go to the right of gaming pc it will show up on the left side of server monitor 2.  If you go to the left of gaming pc, you show up on the right side of server monitor 1.  Since the server monitors are natively setup to be next to each other, you can go off the left side of server monitor 1 to get to server monitor 2.

I'll test it out within the next week and update this if it works.

Answer (score 6):

Synergy can't do that, yet. We are planning to get this included in a  Synergy 2.x release but aren't able to give an ETA as yet.

We have his on our Github: [Independent grid-less screen positioning #4173](https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/4173)

For now you'll have to use Synergy keeping one computers screens as one unit and another computers screens as another.

Comment: If you implement this, I will buy your software!

Comment: How about if I had a 4th screen and made a T shape out of it?  gaming monitor in the middle, server monitors to the right, left, and above the gaming monitor.  To get to the server monitors I'd just move the mouse up to the top screen, then going to the left or right will go to the monitors on the sides. Seems similar enough to Martin's post here: http://symless.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1515#p4968 so it might work

Comment: That would work, but as Synergy will treat the three monitors as one single "virtual" screen and will allow you to move from the Server screens to the Gaming screen across the bottoms of all three (it would spring out at a relative position on the top of the Gaming screen) I'd recommend having the Server screens all next to one another and the gaming screen by itself.